# why is this code giving this output - "HCF is: 1" whenever a%b != 0?

Tags: c

This program is made to find the HCF of two integers a and b by the formula/algorithm - 'a = bq +r' where a and b are two numbers, q being the quotient and r is the remainder.
here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int a, b;
printf("enter both numbers a>b to find HCF\n");
scanf("%d %d",&a, &b);
int q, r, hcf;
if(a%b == 0) {
    r = 0;
    hcf = r;
} else {
    q = a/b;
    r = a%b;
}
int i;
for(i = r; i = 0;) {
    a = b;
    b = i;
    hcf = b;
    q = a/b;
    i = a%b;

}
printf("HCF is: %d", hcf);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i = r; i = 0;)` - did you mean `i == 0`?

Comment: is the `for` loop correct? The stopping condition looks like an assignment. Is this intended? If so, then if I remember correctly the condition evaluates to false right away, since `i` is 0 and it so happens that you're always printing the uninitialized value of `hcf` which concindentially always prints 1.

Comment: thanks for the comment sir! the stopping condition here is not an assignment. what i meant by `i = 0` is stop the loop when i equals 0. i contradict that i `i` is `0` as nowhere i have written it! please comment again to help! once again, thanks! @RuudHelderman

Answer (score 2):

The for loop is not correct. You need to use `==` instead of `=`. The `=` operator is for assignment, `==` is for comparison. Also, you want the loop to stop when `i == 0` so the condition should be `i != 0`. The following loop works for me:

```
for(i = r; i != 0; ) {
   a = b;
   b = i;
   hcf = b;
   i = a%b;
}
```